# quicksort implementation trouble

Tags: c, debugging, out-of-memory, quicksort

I am encountering the problems in executing the quicksort algorithm.
THere is a error i am encountering but unable to find where the problem is. if someone could point where the error is i will be thankfull.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quickSort(arr,0,n-1);
    printArray(arr,0,n-1);
}

//Quicksort Function
void quickSort(int arr[],int low,int high){
    if (low < high){

        int pi=partition(arr,low,high);
        quickSort(arr,low,pi-1);//takes care of lower set of numbers
        quickSort(arr,pi+1,high);//takes care of higher elements above pivot
    }
}

//Function for partitioing, in my program i am cosidering pivot as the element at high or the last element
int partition(int arr[],int low,int high){
    int i,j;
    i=(low-1);
    int pivot=arr[high];
    for(j=low;j<=high;j++){
        if(arr[j]<=pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}

//function to print array
void printArray(int arr[],int low,int high){
    int i;
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

//function to swap two elements of array
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Comment: What error? And format your code.

Comment: Have you tried maybe printing the state of the items to be sorted in each iteration of your algorith, and comparing that with exected output when you do the sorting manually? What have you done to try and find the error? SO is not a debugger for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple Implementation of `QuickSort` Algorithm

```
 void q_sort(int v[],int left,int right)
 {
   int i,last;

   if(left>=right)
   return;

   swap(v,left,(left+right)/2);
   last=left;

   for(i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
      if(v[i]<v[left])
        swap(v,++last,i);

   swap(v,left,last);
   q_sort(v,left,last-1);
   q_sort(v,last+1,right);  
}

void swap(int v[],int i,int j)
{
   int temp;
   if(i!=j){
       temp=v[i];
       v[i]=v[j];
       v[j]=temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement of your partition() -

```
        if(arr[j]<=pivot){
```

Change it to -

```
        if(arr[j]<pivot){
```